# How to open another page in pop up modal on click of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page one.html that contains a hyperlink

```
<a href="#">Open second page<a/>
```

When this link is clicked I want to open second.html in a pop up modal.

My second page contains a simple table which I want to show, like:

```
<html>
  <div class="table-responsive-md">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>adidas</td>
                <td>one of the top sport brand.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Do you use any library or framework such as jQuery or React? In any case, I recommand you have a look at tutorials on the web to achieve this. For example: [Simple popup modal with vanilla JavaScript (on Medium).](https://medium.com/@GistCoding/simple-popup-modal-with-vanilla-javascript-a14515ec630b)

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://superdevresources.com/open-links-popup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content you want to display is on an other site the only way is to use iframes. So you would have your modal with the iframe inside it pointing to the external source and being set invisible. When clicking on the link, a Javascript Eventlistener would set the modal visible (i.e. manipulate CSS display). The href attribut of the link is empty.

But using iframes ist kind a out of date. Instead modern Web Apps use Rest Endpoints to request the data in a format like json, parse it and render the data within your App.